# How to show placeholder or error text if response from API is not correct in Angular

Tags: html, angular

How do I show some placeholder text, if the response from an Api for the `{{news,content}}`comes back as follows:

```
[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.description)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.videoCountText)]]
```

In my html I am binding as follows:

```
 <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let news of newsData">
            <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="news.id">
            <div class="card mt-3 mb-3">
                <img [src]="news.src" [title]="news.title" src="{{news.urlToImage}}" class="card-img-top news-img" alt="image" onerror="this.src='../../../../assets/images/img-error.jpg';">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="mt-0 block-with-text-2">{{news.title}}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text block-with-text">{{news.content}}</p>
                  <a href="{{news.url}}" class="card-link mb-3" target="_blank">Read more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-template>  
        </div>
```

As you can see I have got some error handling on the image, but need some on the `{{news.content}}`Any idea's?

Comment: In which input do you want to show the placeholder ? And can you be more clear about the condition ?

Comment: its in the question: `{{news.content}}` and condition should be if the data looks like `[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.description)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.videoCountText)]]` then show the placeholder text

Comment: You mean a text replacement right ? Placeholder attribute only works for input tag

Comment: yes, i mean like fallback text

Answer (score 0):

If the `{{news.content}}` will only exist if there was no error then you can simply check for its existence in the `news` object. You can either use a conditional or have two

, one for the content and one for the error.

```
<p *ngIf="news.content">{{news.content}}</p>
<p *ngIf="!news.content">{{noContent}}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{{news.content? news.content : noContent}}
```

The `noContent` is simply a string you have defined in the controller for the template.

If your error detection differs from this model i.e. `news.content` may exist alongside an error you'll need to change the logic appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show a text replacement when news.content has no value just add this

```
<p class="card-text block-with-text">{{news.content || 'your text replacement'}}</p>
```

For your example you can do this:

```
// Component: wyw = Whatever you want
contentHandler(data: any){
    if(getSimpleString(data.title) !== 'wyw' || getSimpleString(data.description) !== 'wyw' || getSimpleString(data.videoCountText) !== 'wyw'){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then

```
// Html
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="contentHandler(news)">
    <h5 class="mt-0 block-with-text-2">{{news.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text block-with-text">{{news.content}}</p>
    <a href="{{news.url}}" class="card-link mb-3" target="_blank">Read more</a>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!contentHandler(news)">
    Your text replacement
</div>
```

Comment: Ok what if I just wanted to target if the response was `[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.description)]]
[[getSimpleString(data.videoCountText)]]`?